# Responsiveness layout - reorganizing divs

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there any way to go from desktop layout to mobile layout as shown on the image below using `CSS`? (responsiveness layout).

On the image below, every square is a `div` including the red square (anonymous).
I have the following `divs`: `{A, B, C, D, red}`.

On my requirements it is not possible to move the `div` A inside the red `div` (html source code). I just need the rendering takes care to put `div` A after `div` B.

[image]

Below you have a sample you can run by yourself.
Also you have the jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/tjztgn5d/

```css
* {
  font-family: Arial;
}
#red {
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid #F00;
  padding: 10px;
}
.header {
  padding: 10px auto;
  text-align: center;
}
#A {
  float: left;
  width: 140px;
  height: 210px;
  border: 1px solid #D79B00;
}
#A > .header {
  background-color: #FFE6CC;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #D79B00;
}
#B {
  width: 140px;
  height: 188px;
  border: 1px solid #6C8EBF;
}
#B > .header {
  background-color: #DAE8FC;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #6C8EBF;
}
#C, #D {
  width: 140px;
  height: 88px;
}
#C {
  border: 1px solid #B85450;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#C > .header {
  background-color: #F8CECC;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #B85450;
}
#D {
  border: 1px solid #9673A6;
}
#D > .header {
  background-color: #E1D5E7;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #9673A6;
}
```

```html
<div id="A">
  <div class="header">A</div>
</div>
<div id="red">
  <div id="B" style="float:left;margin-right:10px;">
    <div class="header">B</div>
  </div>
  <div style="float:left;">
    <div id="C">
      <div class="header">C</div>
    </div>
    <div id="D">
      <div class="header">D</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any idea on how to achieve this without `Javascript`?

Comment: **Flexbox** will work

Comment: could you help me with the code on `jsfiddle`?, with `flexbox` can I render the `div A` inside the `red div` after `div B`?

Comment: Not without flattening the red container.  If you do that, you can leverage flex `order`.

Comment: check this [https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/]

Comment: https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/vWEMWw

Comment: Can I keep the `red div` when using `flexbox`?

Comment: Can you change the HTML structure at all?

Comment: A is not nested inside the red div and in the second image it's under B which is nested inside the red div! that wont work with flex you need JS unless you add A inside red div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this can be done without altering the HTML or using Javascript. The trick is to use absolute positioning. It can work in your case because you are using fixed sizes anyway.

https://jsfiddle.net/anzL79py/

This is what I have added:

```
@media (max-width: 512px) {
  /* erase inline styles. dont use them anymore! */
  #B {
    float: unset !important;
    margin-right: unset !important;
  }
  #B + div {
    float: unset !important;
  }

  #A {
    position: absolute;
    left: 19px;
    top: 218px;
  }
  #B {
    margin-bottom: 230px;
  }
}
```

And the full snippet.

```css
* {
  font-family: Arial;
}
#red {
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid #F00;
  padding: 10px;
}
.header {
  padding: 10px auto;
  text-align: center;
}
#A {
  float: left;
  width: 140px;
  height: 210px;
  border: 1px solid #D79B00;
}
#A > .header {
  background-color: #FFE6CC;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #D79B00;
}
#B {
  width: 140px;
  height: 188px;
  border: 1px solid #6C8EBF;
}
#B > .header {
  background-color: #DAE8FC;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #6C8EBF;
}
#C, #D {
  width: 140px;
  height: 88px;
}
#C {
  border: 1px solid #B85450;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#C > .header {
  background-color: #F8CECC;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #B85450;
}
#D {
  border: 1px solid #9673A6;
}
#D > .header {
  background-color: #E1D5E7;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #9673A6;
}

@media (max-width: 512px) {
  /* erase inline styles. dont use them anymore! */
  #B {
    float: unset !important;
    margin-right: unset !important;
  }
  #B + div {
    float: unset !important;
  }
  
  #A {
    position: absolute;
    left: 19px;
    top: 218px;
  }
  #B {
    margin-bottom: 230px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="A">
  <div class="header">A</div>
</div>
<div id="red">
  <div id="B" style="float:left;margin-right:10px;">
    <div class="header">B</div>
  </div>
  <div style="float:left;">
    <div id="C">
      <div class="header">C</div>
    </div>
    <div id="D">
      <div class="header">D</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case by not using JS, it would be better to use

> **Bootstrap Column** + **Flexbox** in Media Query

```css
.contain{
  max-height:800px;
}
.A{
  color:white;
  font-size:100px;
  background:red;
  height:100vh;
  border:10px solid white;
}
.B{
  color:white;
  font-size:100px;
  background:green;
  height:100vh;
  border:10px solid white;

}
.C{
  color:white;
  font-size:100px;
  background:blue;
  height:50vh;
    border:10px solid white;

}
.D{
  color:white;
  font-size:100px;
  background:pink;
  height:50vh;
    border:10px solid white;

}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .contain{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
  }
  .A{
    order:2;
    border:0px;
  }
  .B{
    order:1;
    border:0px;
  }
  .three{
    order:3;
    border:0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class='container'>
<div class="row contain">
  <div class="col-sm-4 A">1</div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 B">2</div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 three">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12 C">3</div>
      <div class="col-sm-12 D">4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```